# Not unique Tables/Aliases wp-query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I need to get some values for my annoucements, and i use sql custome query like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID 
  FROM wp_posts 
  JOIN wp_postmeta 
    ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id 
  JOIN wp_postmeta 
    ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id 
   AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'zachodniopomorskie' 
   AND wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%%' 
 WHERE 1=1 
   AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'refresh_date' 
   AND wp_posts.post_type = 'announcement' 
   AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
 GROUP 
    BY wp_posts.ID 
 ORDER 
    BY wp_postmeta.meta_value DESC 
 LIMIT 0, 15
```

But i got error like this:  [Not unique table/alias: 'wp_postmeta']

I tried to make some alias but (AS) but than i have error within  [Not unique table/alias: 'alias_value']

Can someone please help me, how to create query like this ?

Comment: Just use a different alias each time (although I don't understand why you need to join the table twice) - and note that in the absence of any aggregating funcitons, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate.

Comment: ...although 'West Pomeranian' seems like an unlikely 'refresh_date'

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Looks as duplicate `  JOIN wp_postmeta 
    ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id 
  JOIN wp_postmeta 
    ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id `

Answer (score 0):

You should use aliases, see the new code

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID 
  FROM wp_posts  as p
  JOIN wp_postmeta  as pm1
    ON p.ID = pm1.post_id 
  JOIN wp_postmeta as pm2
    ON p.ID = pm2.post_id 
   AND pm2.meta_value = 'zachodniopomorskie'  (i suppose you wanted pm2 here?)
   AND p.post_title LIKE '%%' 
 WHERE 1=1 
   AND pm1.meta_key = 'refresh_date' 
   AND p.post_type = 'announcement' 
   AND p.post_status = 'publish'
 GROUP 
    BY p.ID 
 ORDER 
    BY pm1.meta_value DESC 
 LIMIT 0, 15
```

adjust the conditions to meet your goal, but that's the point. You need to instruct your DB on which table you are going to work on